# Trouble With Specifying Correct ng-repeat Tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to AngularJS.

I am trying to display blog entries on a page using ng-repeat.

I am running into a bit of confusion how to properly specifying the correct attribute for the ng-repeat tag.

**My JSON data source.   This is converted using X2JS from an XML file:**

```
{
    "blog": {
        "article": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "author": "eat-sleep-code",
                "title": {
                    "__cdata": "The first article."
                },
                "content": {
                    "__cdata": "\n        This is my first article in my test site.\n      "
                },
                "createdate": "2014-05-09"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "author": "eat-sleep-code",
                "title": {
                    "__cdata": "The second article."
                },
                "content": {
                    "__cdata": "\n        This is my second article in my test site.  This article's create date is actually earlier.\n      "
                },
                "createdate": "2014-05-08"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**My partial view:**

```
<article ng-repeat="article in data.blog">
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    {{content}}
    {{id}}  
</article>
```

**My app.js:**

```
//Define an angular module for our app
var app = angular.module('eatsleepcode', ['ngRoute']); 

//Define Routing
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {    
        $routeProvider.      
            /* Root */
            when('/', {templateUrl: 'views/home.html', controller: 'DefaultController'}).
            when('/blog', {templateUrl: 'views/blog.html', controller: 'BlogController'}).  
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/404'
            });
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
            $locationProvider.hashPrefix("!");
}]);  




/* Controllers */
app.controller('DefaultController', function($scope) {});

app.controller('BlogController', function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    $http({method: 'GET', url: '//eat-sleep-code.com/data/blog.xml'}).
        success(function(data, status) {
            var x2js = new X2JS();
            var jsonString = JSON.stringify(x2js.xml_str2json(data));
            $scope.data = jsonString;
            $scope.status = status;
            console.log('DATA: ' + jsonString);
            console.log('STATUS: ' + status);
        }).
        error(function(data, status) {
            $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
            $scope.status = status;
            console.log('STATUS: ' + status);
        });
});
```

When I view the elements in Google Chrome, I see: <! -- ngRepeat: article in data.blog -- > but nothing is actually being repeated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `ng-repeat` on an array and data.blog is an object not an array.

instead of

```
<article ng-repeat="article in data.blog">
```

try using this:

```
<article ng-repeat="article in data.blog.article">
    <h2>{{article.title.__cdata}}</h2>
```

`article` is the property which you wish to enumerate.

**Edit** Also note that the elements you wish to display `title` have a child property that contains the text you wish to display named `__cdata`

Comment: Note: I am aware that you can enumerate through the keys of an object via `ng-repeat` but don't find that to be necessary information in the context of this question/answer.

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately, still no output other than the Angular-generated comment.

Comment: See the edit that I just added, you will also need to adapt your view to show the properties that are actually contained within your model. Or tweak the data in the model to suit your template.

Comment: This is my current template: `<article ng-repeat="article in data.blog.article"> {{id}} <h2>{{title.__cdata}}</h2>   {{content.__cdata}}</article>`

Comment: @eat-sleep-code Don't you mean `{{article.id}}`? `id` isn't defined anywhere...it's a property of `article`

Comment: @Ian Excellent point, I updated my answer to show that detail underneath the DOM element with the `ng-repeat` directive. Clarification: when using `ng-repeat` you are creating a new scope and the accessor to that new scope is `x` given `ng-repeat="x in y"`

Comment: Good point Ian, now changed to `<article ng-repeat="article in data.blog.article">{{article.id}}<h2>{{article.title.__cdata}}</h2>{{article.content.__cdata}}</article>`  Still the only output is: <! -- ngRepeat: article in data.blog.article -- >

Comment: @eat-sleep-code Another "problem" is: `$scope.data = jsonString;`. `$scope.data` now contains a string (since you've `JSON.stringify`'ed the object). You need `$scope.data` to be a JS object. I'm not exactly sure what `x2js.xml_str2json(data)` returns, as the docs on the Google Code site says it converts it to "JSON"...a string or JS object? You may need to do `$scope.data = JSON.parse(x2js.xml_str2json(data));` (or simply not modify `data`...you'll have to debug that)

Comment: Gah, changed this to: var jsonObject = JSON.parse(x2js.xml_str2json(data));
$scope.data = jsonObject;
Now get an error of: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)

Comment: This syntax worked: var jsonObject = x2js.xml_str2json(data); $scope.data = jsonObject;

Comment: @eat-sleep-code I had a feeling that might be the way. The docs are confusing as they say "json" is returned from that function. But there's no real concept of "json" in JavaScript, so I wasn't sure if it was a string or object